# Geometrical Interpretation of Linearly independent vectors

Tags: matrices, vectors

Suppose we have two **linearly independent vectors $X_1$ and $X_2$** as:  $$X_1=(0 \quad 1 \quad 1) \quad and \quad X_2=(1 \quad 1 \quad -1)$$
then how can we **interpret it as geometrically** or what does it **signifies geometrically**? please help....?

Comment: Geometrically, two vectors are linearly dependent *iff* they are collinear. If they are linearly *independent* then they span a 2D plane. If you are looking for a more formal answer, then you'll need to provide more context to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If **two** vectors are linearly independent then they are **not co-linear**.

If **three** vectors are linearly independent then they are **not co-planar**.

If **four** vectors are linearly independent then they are **not co-spatial** (in a 4-dimensional hyperspace) and so on.